# Can the paper by Monz et al. (2015) be regarded as a real implementation of Shor's algorithm?

Tags: shors-algorithm, experimental-realization

I'm studying about the Shor algorithm and I wonder whether the paper below can be regarded as a real implementation of the Shor algorithm:

https://arxiv.org/abs/1507.08852

In this paper, they tried to recycle the first register 2 times for factoring 15 so that they can realize 3 qubits in the first register.

But for implementing the Shor algorithm without any prior knowledge and satisfying the best approximation condition of the continued fraction expansion algorithm, shouldn't it be recycled 7 times so that it can satisfy 8 qubits (which is the requirement for factoring 15)?

Also, I wonder whether applying the optimization process on the unitary operator where the initial quantum state in the second register is changed is reasonable generally and can be regarded as part of the modular exponentiation (this has been applied in every Shor algorithm experiment, of course in the above paper too). If so, can we regard the Fig 1.(b) case in the above paper as a real implementation of the Shor's algorithm WHEN the first register is recycled 7 times?

Comment: I basically asked this question 6 years ago! https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/37113/35155

Answer (score 3):

It's fundamentally not possible to demonstrate "scalable" factoring by doing $n=15$. If the approach was so scalable, it should have actually scaled up and done larger numbers!

In my opinion, a "scalable" system should be able to factor any number less than 1000. And it should be able to factor this number that's less than 1000 *reliably*; using less than 5 runs of the quantum part of Shor's algorithm (on average). For numbers larger than 1000, more than 5 attempts would be okay, but not too much more. Otherwise rolling dice, instead of running the quantum computer, would work just as well. This is actually extremely demanding: it implies the ability to do tens of thousands of gates without a bit flip or phase flip error changing the outcome.

> I wonder whether applying the optimization process on the unitary operator where the initial quantum state in the second register is changed is reasonable generally

This optimization is totally valid; it works on all cases. But, when factoring big numbers, this optimization affects such a tiny fraction of the computation that it's completely irrelevant. Whereas, for the paper you cited, this optimization is removing 30% of the circuit! This is an optimization whose benefits don't scale.

> shouldn't [the ancilla] be recycled 7 times [instead of 2]?

Yes, I think they should have done 8 multiplications instead of 3 if they wanted to claim they were "really" doing Shor's algorithm.

Comment: Thank your for your reply! May I ask you which part has been removed in their paper?

Comment: The fact that the first two operations are simpler than the last one is the part that was "removed". It's perfectly valid as an optimization, but in larger cases reducing the cost of the first two multiplications is just negligible because there are so many multiplications total.

Comment: Why does it have to be "using less than 5 runs"?

Comment: @user1271772 the reason for the limit on the number of runs is to prevent solving the problem by random guessing. For semiprimes N between 100 and 1000, if you pick a random number 32 times and compute its gcd versus N, you're likely to find a factor of N just by luck. Limiting it to 5 keeps you well away from that degenerate solution.

Comment: There's 143 primes between 100 and 1000, so why is it that the quantum computer should only be allowed to run Shor's algorithm 5 times?

Comment: @user1271772 You only need to hit a number R where gcd(R, N) isn't 1 and isn't N. That's pretty likely. Or, if you do trial division, you only need to try 10 primes to factor any semiprime below 1000. Numbers below 1000 are *REALLY EASY* to factor by sheer accident, so the number of tries should be extremely limited. That's just how I feel about it.

Comment: In the worst case, [trial division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trial_division#Speed) would require pi(2^5) = 11 attempts starting with trial = 2 and going up to trial = sqrt(N), for N = 2^(5*2) = 1024, so I don't disagree with you that for numbers below 1000, about 10 trial division attempts is sufficient. I just don't see why Shor's algorithm would have to be done in fewer than 5 attempts. Why not 9? It also wasn't completely clear to me that the sentence about 5 attempts was still referring to factoring numbers below 1000, but I've made an edit to clarify that, if you're okay with it!

Comment: I'm not sure if the number of run is actually important for small numbers less than 1000 because those numbers can be factored easily using classical computers. Even though Shor's algorithm run is less than 5 times, conventional computers can factor those numbers during the 5 times run of Shor's algorithm. Then, what is the use of 5 times of running? Imo, there is no meaning in the number of run.